# How to swap Alt+PgUp and Alt+PgDn inside an mstsc window, with autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

Context description: As a Windows admin, I often use mstsc.exe from my client machine to connect to Windows server remote desktop. I realize that，when mstsc is the active window on my client machine:

- <kbd>Alt+PgUp</kbd> acts like <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> inside the server
- <kbd>Alt+PgDn</kbd> acts like <kbd>Alt+Shift+Tab</kbd> inside the server

But, I firmly believe that Microsoft's PgUp/PgDn designation here is counter intuitive. Reason: [ Holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> ] and [ press <kbd>Tab</kbd> multiple times ] cycles through windows from **top to bottom** in z-order(Windows API terminology), so it is more like a **page down** operation. So, <kbd>Alt+PgDn</kbd> should map to <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt+Shift+Tab</kbd> .

Therefore, I tried to use Autohotkey to do the key mapping. According to [official doc](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm), I write the snippet:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class TscShellContainerClass

!PGUP:: !PGDN
!PGDN:: !PGUP

#IfWinActive ahk_class
```

It almost work, but fails eventually. The symptom is: When I press <kbd>Alt+PgDn</kbd>, the switching window appears and the focus moves, but on releasing the keys, the switch does not actually occur - VERY STRANGE!

[image]

Can someone help me out?

Autohotkey version: 1.1.13.01 , Client machine is Windows 7 x64, server machine is Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding UP hotkeys as well?  Something like this...

```
!PGUP:: !PGDN
!PGDN:: !PGUP
!PGUP UP:: !PGDN UP
!PGDN UP:: !PGUP UP
```

That might not be the exact syntax for sending the up sequence (it may be something like `Send !{PGDN UP}`, but just an idea to test.